# Prove that $G$ is injective if and only $ G \circ (H \cap J)= (G \circ H) \cap (G \circ J) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$G$ is a functional graph if and only if

$(x_1,y)\in G$ and $(x_2,y)\in G$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x_1=x_2$

$Problem:$

Let $G$ be a functional graph. Prove that $G$ is injective if and only if for
arbitrary graphs $J$ and $H$

$$ G \circ (H \cap J)= (G \circ H) \cap  (G \circ J)  $$

I have not been able to prove that if for
arbitrary graphs $J$ and $H$

$$ G \circ (H \cap J)= (G \circ H) \cap  (G \circ J)  $$ then $G$ is injective

Can anyone help me, give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x_1,y) \in G$ and $(x_2, y) \in G$. Let $H = \{(y, x_1)\}$ and $J = \{(y, x_2)\}$. Then $y \xrightarrow{H} x_1 \xrightarrow{G} y$ and $y \xrightarrow{J} x_2 \xrightarrow{G} y$. Thus $(y, y) \in (G \circ H) \cap (G \circ J)$. Since $(G \circ H) \cap  (G \circ J) = G \circ (H \cap J)$, one gets $(y, y) \in G \circ (H \cap J)$. Thus $H \cap J$ is nonempty, which implies that $x_1 = x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume aGu, bGu and a /= b.
Let H = {(d,a)}, J = {(d,b)}
Then
(H $\cap$ J)$\circ$G is empty.
H$\circ$G $\cap$ J$\circ$G contains (d,u).
Thus a = b.

Either the problem was miscopied or you are using the reverse definition of composition.